# Many to Many Relationship Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-relationship

Well, I have tried to do a Many-to-Many relationship using Entity framework, where the Join table has more than just two ID, it will have two other columns Active and DateUpdate. So here is the designer.

[Tables Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODwcm.png)

When I did the context importing from an existing database, it look to work well. But I got a big question, is it right have the direction going from Group[0].GroupUser[0].User and going back in the same case? And in that way creating a lot of redundancy has showed in the picture below? Or is it something wrong?

[Redundancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzeII.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is not redundancy. `Group[0].GroupUser[0].User` is a reference to `User` and `User` has a navigation property to the `GroupUser`. Therefore, when you see `User` and then navigate to `GroupUser` of that user, the `GroupUser` will have a reference to `User`. If you keep expanding, it will keep showing you the same `User` and `GroupUser`.